# jQuery json doesn't work at all

Tags: jquery, json

i try to fetch all my json objects from php, but doesn't seem to work, i cannot get any data out of it.

JSON:

```
  [{"courtid":"4","bookingid":"22673","centername":"Copenhagen","time":"8:9","date":"27-8-2013"},{"courtid":"3","bookingid":"22702","centername":"Copenhagen","time":"17:18","date":"27-8-2013"},{"courtid":"4","bookingid":"26422","centername":"Copenhagen","time":"7:9","date":"31-12-2013"},{"courtid":"5","bookingid":"26423","centername":"Copenhagen","time":"7:9","date":"31-12-2013"},{"courtid":"13","bookingid":"26424","centername":"Copenhagen","time":"7:9","date":"31-12-2013"}]
```

My jQuery ajax:

```
$.getJSON("http://f??????dboldfabrikken.dk/api/index.php?module=getAvailableGames",function(msg){
$.each(msg.courtid,function(index,item){
    alert(index + "..."+item);
});
});
```

replace ?????? with o to try it yourself.

What do i have to do?

Comment: Change `$.each(msg.courtid` to `$.each(msg`

Comment: try this item.courtid to get courtid

Comment: You json results in an array of objects, however you seem to be treating it as an object (msg.courtid). What does your console say? also, even if json was an object, msg.courtid is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The message is an array, so iterate through the array to access individual properties of the items in the array

```
$.getJSON("http://f??????dboldfabrikken.dk/api/index.php?module=getAvailableGames", function (msgs) {
    $.each(msgs, function (index, item) {
        alert(index + "..." + JSON.stringify(item));// here you can access item.courtid
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $.getJSON("http://f??????dboldfabrikken.dk/api/index.php?module=getAvailableGames",function(msg){
        $.each(msg,function(index,item){
            alert(index + "..."+item.courtid);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify your network reponse from you query?

Apparently the object that you get is an array, so it would be:

```
$.each(msg, function(index, item))
```

etc ...